# Is there anyway to import SVN Windows repository to Linux?

Tags: svn

I used to do my PHP work on Windows. I used SVN and my repository is on an NTFS folder. I installed Linux on one of the partitions and I want to import that repository to SVN linux. Any way?

Answer (score 5):

Use `svnadmin dump > dump.svn` on Windows and `svnadmin load /path/to/repo < dump.svn` on Linux. Previously you should create an empty repository at Linux host.

Answer (score 2):

Just copy the repository C:\svnrepo to linux /var/svnrepo,

(How to copy? you may package it to .zip file and then upload to Linux though FTP, 
So you don't have to setup SAMBA and all)
(You can upload by sftp if the Linux box is behind a firewall, which cause the ftp data connection couldn't be established)

in Linux, create a new user svn with password svn, change its shell in /etc/passwd from /bin/sh to /bin/false,

```
  /var$ chown -R svn:svn svnrepo
  /var$ chmod -R 664 svnrepo
```

And in the /etc/group file, add users who will write to svn to the svn group. 
(Comment out the password-db in svnrepo/conf/svnserve.conf, so the svnserve will use the system user instead)

And, if you created the svn repo in windows using subversion 1.6+, don't forget to install a   subversion 1.6+ also in the Linux, otherwise subversion 1.5 doesn't support the new format of subversion 1.6 repo. In such case, you may need to dump first and then load it again.

And you SHOULD always use a single repo, if you decided to move svn-repo to linux, then don't use the one in win anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can mount the NTFS volume containing the repository under Linux, and then checkout from the repository location to somewhere in your Linux filesystem.

Alternatively just use the working copy you've presumably already checked out under Windows, when you mount the NTFS volume.